# What will happen if I install Ubuntu GNOME over a regular Ubuntu install?

Tags: system-installation

If I install Ubuntu GNOME over my already existing Ubuntu install what will happen?

Is it same as doing fresh install (all installed programs/settings/etc will be deleted)?

Comment: Are You Going To install gnome-shell by apt-get?

Comment: nope, i want to reinstall it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your current installation of Ubuntu is working correctly, there is no need to re-install just to change your desktop environment to Gnome.

You can convert an existing installation without a re-install.  [The procedure is described in the UbuntuGNOME wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/Installation#Cross-grading_from_Ubuntu_To_Ubuntu_GNOME).

In simple terms all you need to do is install the package `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` which contains all of the customisations to convert your installation to UbuntuGNOME.  Then, you can optionally remove some other packages if you no longer need the old Ubuntu desktop.

> First, you install the Ubuntu GNOME desktop, and enable GDM.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-deskop
> ```
>
> dpkg will prompt asking which display manager you want to use, select 'gdm'
>   Optionally, you can remove unneeded packages from Ubuntu.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-default-settings
>
> sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-desktop
>
> sudo apt-get autoremove
> ```